# How can I run dangerous code without the danger

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to get into the world of pentesting and stuff like that. I found a code that piqued my interest. It unfortunately will format your hard drives and wipe them clean, and that is never any fun. I am trying to change the default photo and stuff on this file but I do not want to risk clicking it. How would I be able to do all this but npt have to worry about the risk.

Comment: Run it in a virtual machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep it isolated on a 'sacrificial harddrive' - One which only has an OS and the bare minimum of software on it, and which you don't allow to connect to any other harddisks (ie you isolate it in your machine with no other harddisks and keep it away from your home network)...

Or try running it within a sandboxed 'virtual drive' as the above poster suggested

Answer (score 0):

Setup a vm environment with https://www.virtualbox.org/ or something similar.  Then run the code on there.